# Get login name using email address with Powershell

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell, user-management

I need a powershell script, to get login names using the e-mail address. i am having a note with e-mail address of some users. I want to get login IDs and account information of the users in the domain.  Can any one help on this.

Regards,
Karthick.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this using:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Emailaddress -eq 'Test@email.com'}
```

Comment: Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq 'test@email.com'} -Properties name | Select Name

Comment: Would this work for millions of users? and how much time will it approximately take?

Answer (score 3):

This command will take input from a TXT file containing user email addresses and output the listed user properties to a CSV file...

```
Get-Content C:\users.txt | ForEach-Object { ^
  Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $_} -Properties DistinguishedName,Name,SamAccountName,DisplayName,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Enabled ^
  | Select-Object DistinguishedName,Name,SamAccountName,DisplayName,EmailAddress,LastLogonDate,Enabled ^
  | Export-CSV C:\users.csv -Append ^
}
```